# Flat BOM structure to hierarchical, detecting cycles in your tree / graph

Tags: php, hierarchy, hierarchical-data, hierarchical, flat

I've got many<>many table which stores Bill Of Material hierarchy data like:

> id | childId
>
> a | b
>
> a | c
>
> c | d
>
> d | a

I need to find closed loops, like in this case `d` points back to `a`, which breaks the system since some recursive functions would never stop.

My idea was to transform this data structure from flat to hierarchical, then iterate over hierarchical structure using recursion.

I am looking up some knowledge on Web and most of the solutions of transforming flat to nested structure, cover the case where there is:

> id | parentId

structure, where top level items has `parentId` set to root value (e.g. zero).

I am a self-taught systems developer for many years, but this is a moment where I am lacking the education many of you had during studies :)

EDIT: Graphical examples

```
Valid trees:
a)
      A              
     / \             
    B   C               
         \
          D
         / \
        E   F

b)

      K -> E
     / \
    G   B
   /|\ 
  H I J


Invalid tree (closed loop)
      A             
     / \ 
    B   C<----\
         \     |
          D   /
         / \ /
        E   F
             \
              G
             /|\
            H I J
```

Comment: Indeed interesting, but in my case it is not a Linked list, but rather tree.

Answer (score 0):

After bit of a trial and error, here is what I've came up with.

Given the flat list of relations, it builds the lookup, which is then used in a recursive traversal function. Traversal function "remembers" the original part that was requested (`$initialPart`) and throws an Exception when cycle is detected. 
E.g. exception: `Loop detected: f=>c=>d=>f!`

Script:

```
$rows = [
    ['assemblyId' => 'a', 'partId' => 'b'],
    ['assemblyId' => 'a', 'partId' => 'c'],
    ['assemblyId' => 'c', 'partId' => 'd'],
    ['assemblyId' => 'd', 'partId' => 'e'],
    ['assemblyId' => 'd', 'partId' => 'f'],
    ['assemblyId' => 'f', 'partId' => 'c'],
    ['assemblyId' => 'f', 'partId' => 'g'],
    ['assemblyId' => 'g', 'partId' => 'h'],
    ['assemblyId' => 'g', 'partId' => 'i'],
    ['assemblyId' => 'g', 'partId' => 'j'],
];

$assemblyLookup = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $assemblyLookup[$row['assemblyId']][$row['partId']] = $row;
}

function getTree(&$part, $initialPart = null, $path = '', $level = 0, $maxLevel = 100) {
    global $assemblyLookup;

    if ($initialPart === null) {
        $initialPart = $part;
    }

    if ($level >= $maxLevel) {
        return;
    }

    $path .= '=>' . $part['partId'];
    if (is_array($assemblyLookup[$part['partId']])) {
        $lookup = $assemblyLookup[$part['partId']];
        foreach ($lookup as $child) {

            if ($child['partId'] === $initialPart['partId']) {
                $circularPath = substr($path, 2) . '=>' . $child['partId'] . '!';
                throw new Exception("Loop detected: " . $circularPath);
                return;
            }

            $part['children'][$child['partId']] = $child;
            getTree($part['children'][$child['partId']], $initialPart, $path, ++$level, $maxLevel);
        }
    } else {
        $path .= ';';
        $part['path'] = substr($path, 2); // Strip arrow from left side
    }

    return $part;

}

$part = ['partId' => 'f'];

$tree = getTree($part);
```